# Data loss while transferring excel file as Spring response

Tags: spring-mvc, file-transfer

My use case is to have my application download a excel(.xls) from the server. The excel is supposed to have graphs in it.

Here is the server side code for it

```
@RequestMapping(value="/downloadExcel", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String fileName = "excel.xls";
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    try {
        Files.copy(new File(fileName), (OutputStream)response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While opening the excel, I get an alert message saying that 'File Error: Data might have been lost'. And, I couldn't see the graphs in the downloaded excel.

I also checked with setting the content type to 'OCTET-STREAM' but with no luck.

```
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
```

How do I transfer an excel file without data loss?

Comment: could you upload in some place the file so i can try to download the same and check if get same error?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, and I can download excel files with graphics

```
void copyFileToResponse(HttpServletResponse response, File file) throws IOException {
        if(file != null) {
            String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
            if (mimeType == null) {
                logger.debug("mimetype is not detectable, will take default");
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            logger.debug("mimetype : {}", mimeType);
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName()));
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        }
    }
```